# How to check if an items already exists in the listView android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, checkout

I have a listView populated with data getting from another activity. The application works well, but the problem is that I want to have about 200 items in my listView, and I don't want to have duplicates in it. So, my request is to have something which checks if the data are already in the listview and to show a dialog box which tells me that and asks me if I want to add it once again. Thanks !

**Absente.java:**

```
package ro.radioamatori;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class Absente extends Activity {

    private DbHelper_absente mHelpera;
    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    TextView n;




    private ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_fName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_lName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> d = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> stime = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> etime = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> freq = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mode = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> station = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> loc = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> tqsl = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mqsl = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> comm = new ArrayList<String>();

    private ListView userLista;
    private AlertDialog.Builder build;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.absente_listview);

        userLista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lista);




        TextView getTotalCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        getTotalCount.setText("Total conne"+userLista.getCount());

        mHelpera = new DbHelper_absente(this);

        //add new record
        findViewById(R.id.btnAdda).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Adauga_absente.class);
                i.putExtra("update", false);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //click to update data
        userLista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Adauga_absente.class);
                i.putExtra("Fname", user_fName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("Lname", user_lName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("ID", userId.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", d.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", stime.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", etime.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", freq.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", mode.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", station.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", loc.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", tqsl.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", mqsl.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("date", comm.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("update", true);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //long click to delete data
        userLista.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    final int arg2, long arg3) {

                build = new AlertDialog.Builder(Absente.this);
                build.setTitle("Esti sigur ca vrei sa stergi? ");
                build.setMessage("Esti sigur ca vrei sa stergi aceasta inregistrare ?");
                build.setPositiveButton("Da",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(), "Inregistrarea a fost stearsa", 3000).show();

                                dataBase.delete(
                                        DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                                        DbHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                                                + userId.get(arg2), null);
                                displayData();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                build.setNegativeButton("Nu",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = build.create();
                alert.show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        displayData();
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * displays data from SQLite
     */
    private void displayData() {
        dataBase = mHelpera.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

        userId.clear();
        user_fName.clear();
        user_lName.clear();
        d.clear();
        stime.clear();
        etime.clear();
        freq.clear();
        mode.clear();
        station.clear();
        loc.clear();
        tqsl.clear();
        mqsl.clear();
        comm.clear();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
                user_fName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));
                user_lName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));
                d.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_D)));
                stime.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_STIME)));
                etime.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ETIME)));
                freq.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FREQ)));
                mode.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_MODE)));
                station.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_STATION)));
                loc.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LOC)));
                tqsl.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_TQSL)));
                mqsl.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_MQSL)));
                comm.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_COMM)));


            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        NoteAdapter disadpt = new NoteAdapter(Absente.this,userId, user_fName, user_lName, d, stime, etime, freq, mode, station, loc, tqsl, mqsl, comm);
        userLista.setAdapter(disadpt);
        mCursor.close();
    }



}
```

**Adauga_absente:**

```
package ro.radioamatori;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Adauga_absente extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private Button btn_save;
private EditText edit_first,edit_last,d,st,et,f,m,s,l,tq,mq,c;
private DbHelper_absente mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private String id,fname,lname,date,stime,etime,freq,mode,station,loc,tqsl,mqsl,comm;
private boolean isUpdate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adauga_absente);

        btn_save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save_btna); 
        d=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.d);
        st=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.st);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        f=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.f);
        m=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.m);
        s=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.s);
        l=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.l);
        tq=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tq);
        mq=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mq);
        c=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);

        SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat timeF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        String date = dateF.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String time = timeF.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        d.setText(date);
        st.setText(time);


       isUpdate=getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("update");
        if(isUpdate)
        {
            id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
            fname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Fname");
            lname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Lname");
            date=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Date");
            stime=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Stime");
            etime=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Etime");
            freq=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Freq");
            mode=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Mode");
            station=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Station");
            loc=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Loc");
            tqsl=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Tqsl");
            mqsl=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Mqsl");
            comm=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Comm");
            edit_first.setText(fname);
            edit_last.setText(lname);
            d.setText(date);
            st.setText(stime);
            et.setText(etime);
            f.setText(freq);
            m.setText(mode);
            s.setText(station);
            l.setText(loc);
            tq.setText(tqsl);
            mq.setText(mqsl);
            c.setText(comm);


        }

         btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);

         mHelper=new DbHelper_absente(this);

    }

    // saveButton click event 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fname=edit_first.getText().toString().trim();
        lname=edit_last.getText().toString().trim();
        date=d.getText().toString().trim();
        stime=st.getText().toString().trim();
        etime=et.getText().toString().trim();
        freq=f.getText().toString().trim();
        mode=m.getText().toString().trim();
        station=s.getText().toString().trim();
        loc=l.getText().toString().trim();
        tqsl=tq.getText().toString().trim();
        mqsl=mq.getText().toString().trim();
        comm=c.getText().toString().trim();
        if(fname.length()>0 && lname.length()>0 && date.length()>0 && stime.length()>0 && etime.length()>0 && freq.length()>0 && mode.length()>0 && station.length()>0 && loc.length()>0 && tqsl.length()>0 && mqsl.length()>0 && comm.length()>0)
        {
            saveData();
        }
        else
        {


        }



    }

    /**
     * save data into SQLite
     */
    private void saveData(){
        dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,fname);
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME,lname );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_D,date );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_STIME,stime );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_ETIME,etime );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FREQ,freq );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_MODE,mode );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_STATION,station );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LOC,loc );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_TQSL,tqsl );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_MQSL,mqsl );
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_COMM,comm );


        System.out.println("");
        if(isUpdate)
        {    
            //update database with new data 
            dataBase.update(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
        }
        else
        {
            //insert data into database
            dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
        //close database
        dataBase.close();
        finish();


    }

}
```

**NoteAdapter.java:**

```
package ro.radioamatori;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> id;
    private ArrayList<String> firstName;
    private ArrayList<String> lastName;
    private ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> stime = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> etime = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> freq = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mode = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> station = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> loc = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> tqsl = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mqsl = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> comm = new ArrayList<String>();

    public NoteAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id,
            ArrayList<String> fname, ArrayList<String> lname,
            ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<String> stime,
            ArrayList<String> etime, ArrayList<String> freq,
            ArrayList<String> mode, ArrayList<String> station,
            ArrayList<String> loc, ArrayList<String> tqsl,
            ArrayList<String> mqsl, ArrayList<String> comm) {
        this.mContext = c;

        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
        this.date = date;
        this.stime = stime;
        this.etime = etime;
        this.freq = freq;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.station = station;
        this.loc = loc;
        this.tqsl = tqsl;
        this.mqsl = mqsl;
        this.comm = comm;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.note_items, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            mHolder.d = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.d);
            mHolder.st = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.st);
            mHolder.et = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.et);
            mHolder.f = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.f);
            mHolder.m = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.m);
            mHolder.s = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.s);
            mHolder.l = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.l);
            mHolder.tq = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tq);
            mHolder.mq = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.mq);
            mHolder.c = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.c);

            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.txt_id.setText("Connection: " + id.get(pos));
        mHolder.d.setText("Data: " + date.get(pos));
        mHolder.st.setText("Start time: " + stime.get(pos));
        mHolder.et.setText("End time: " + etime.get(pos));
        mHolder.f.setText("Frequency: " + freq.get(pos));
        mHolder.m.setText("Mode: " + mode.get(pos));
        mHolder.s.setText("Station: " + station.get(pos));
        mHolder.l.setText("Location: " + loc.get(pos));
        mHolder.tq.setText("Their QSL: " + tqsl.get(pos));
        mHolder.mq.setText("My QSL: " + mqsl.get(pos));
        mHolder.c.setText("Comment: " + comm.get(pos));


        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView d;
        TextView st;
        TextView et;
        TextView f;
        TextView m;
        TextView s;
        TextView l;
        TextView tq;
        TextView mq;
        TextView c;
        TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_fName;
        TextView txt_lName;
    }

}
```

Comment: first of all use SimpleCursorAdapter,  second before inserting into db check if item already exists in the database

Comment: Why you don't use `Set` instead of `List`? if You correctly override `hashCode()` and `equals(...)` of your item objects it will work well.

Comment: Can't really understand how it work. If u could code me an example, it would be better. Thanks !

Comment: Try to create simple object `User` with fields which you need(`String name, sex... etc`). and store your data in that object, this must be pretty easier to manage your array of data event at ArrayList store. After that you must override in that `User` class `hashCode()` and `equals(..)`. Read little about [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html). And after this manipulation you get nice data manage logic, which will based on [Set](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/set.html).

Comment: Yea. Understood your point, but still nothing. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Solution

- In the `saveData` method, you can just use do a `query` to check if a row exists with same data

Few things I would like to point out

- Instead of using those 10's of `ArrayList`s, consider creating a `model` class called `Note` with all the attributes like `id`, `fname`, `lname`, etc.,
- Use `CursorAdapter` rather than `BaseAdapter` because it is more optimized to pull data from databases
- Also make `saveData` return a `boolean` to indicate whether insertion is successful or not

Comment: You lost me somewhere. A lot of good information. What I beg you is to write this query as you think it would work. Thanks !

Comment: I understand that it is an information overload, but what ever things that I've pointed out are very useful. If you are not in any hurry, sit back and try to understand those points

Comment: Yes. I know what u mean, but without any clearly example, it will be hard too much to understand.

Comment: @Ezekiel just google for any SimpleCursorAdapter tutorial/example and everything will be clear

Comment: Ok. I've looked for it. But the further problem is how to display in a dialog box the information from SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: you get the data not from an adapter (SimpleCursorAdapter) but from a model (sqlite database)

Comment: Yes. I understand that, but really can't do anything. Sorry. Thanks !